# How to change the color of the material depending on the camera view angle?

Tags: texturing, shaders, effects

[image]

The wings of an insect produces a rainbow of colors at certain viewing angle. How do we replicate this kind of effect in a game character?
I know how to bring that effect within blender but if I want to export the model games, is this effect possible with some texture maps?

I have attached a gif image of a game character for reference. I am concerned with its wings that changes its color according to the camera view angle. Its gives a rainbow kind of color or like an oil reflecting... (I don't know the correct term). How do I bring this kind of an output for a game character?

Are these shaders in-built in game engines? or are there any texture map that brings these effect? Please tell me about this.

Comment: Hi. Please use a title that matches the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue so that anyone searching for a similar problem is likely to find it. Remove anything superfluous, avoid using words like "*this*", "*help with*", "*issue*" or "*question about*", instead describe what "it" is. Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors see, answers you get depend heavily on how insightful it is. See [*What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"*](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Comment: Not sure if this is relevant to Blender SE.  The shaders have to built in-engine.  But, those shaders may use textures (for example, to specify the colors at certain angles-- maybe, here, a sphere map aka matcap.)  It's not shaders *or* textures; most of the time, it's shaders *and* textures.